# Splitting Tilemap Image in swing

Tags: java, image-processing, drawimage

I'm having some strange thing happen while trying to split a tilemap to draw to a JPanel. First this is the pertinent piece of code:

```
private void drawTile(Graphics g,MapController mc,int gid){
    int cols = mc.getMap().getTileset().getColumns();
    int x = (gid % cols);

    int y = gid / cols;
    int tilewidth = mc.getTilewidth();
    int tileheight = mc.getTileheight();
    int dx1 = 0;
    int dx2 = dx1+tilewidth;
    int dy1 = 0;
    int dy2 = dy1+tileheight;
    int sx1 = (x)*tilewidth;
    int sx2 = sx1+tilewidth;
    int sy1 = y*tileheight;
    int sy2 = sy1+tileheight;
    g.drawImage(mc.getSpriteImage(), dx1, dy1, dx2, dy2, sx1, sy1, sx2, sy2, null);

}
```

This is inside a loop that iterates through layers on a map and draws each tile to a panel. When I run my program, it works correctly for the most part, but I realized x axis was off by 1 "tile width" (32px). this is the output I get:

This is more or less what it should look like other than the tiles are all 32px off on the x axis

[image: Expectation]

I'm pretty sure this is because i'm converting the CSV to an int[] and the index starts at 0 but my grid starts at 1. Easy fix right? Just subtract 1 from my x value to move the sx1 of my source image 32px to the left.

Revised Code:

```
private void drawTile(Graphics g,MapController mc,int gid){
    int cols = mc.getMap().getTileset().getColumns();

    int x = (gid % cols)-1; //notice the -1

    int y = gid / cols;
    int tilewidth = mc.getTilewidth();
    int tileheight = mc.getTileheight();
    int dx1 = 0;
    int dx2 = dx1+tilewidth;
    int dy1 = 0;
    int dy2 = dy1+tileheight;
    int sx1 = x*tilewidth;
    int sx2 = sx1+tilewidth;
    int sy1 = y*tileheight;
    int sy2 = sy1+tileheight;
    g.drawImage(mc.getSpriteImage(), dx1, dy1, dx2, dy2, sx1, sy1, sx2, sy2, null);

}
```

Now when I run it I get this:

[image: Screwed up]

I put in some troubleshooting lines and it looks like the coordinates I'm sending for the source image are correct. I even tried:

```
g.drawImage(mc.getSpriteImage(), dx1, dy1, dx2, dy2, sx1-32, sy1, sx2, sy2,     null);
```

Everything I've tried is giving me the same results. 
Is there something here that I am missing?

Comment: *"Just subtract 1 from my x value"* - Why not subject `1` from `gid`?

Comment: Changing the gid would affect the Y axis too. It's only the X axis that is off. The gids match up with what is in the CSV file. (I tried that on alread)

Comment: Maybe you draw stuff one over another and then some things aren't visible anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it!
Some of the GIDs in the CSV are 0 to for a transparent tile. When you do the math for the sx1 location then subtract 1, you end up with -1 as the sx1. Apparently awt Graphics doesn't like that so instead of rendering a transparent tile, it doesn't render anything. Thats when things start going wonkey. Interestingly I started this project using JavaFX but decided to go with swing instead. I used the same logic for drawing in FX and didn't have this issue. Here is the Code that works:

```
private void drawTile(Graphics g,MapController mc,int gid){
    int cols = mc.getMap().getTileset().getColumns();

    int x = (gid % cols)-1; 
    if(x<0){x=0};
    int y = gid / cols;
    int tilewidth = mc.getTilewidth();
    int tileheight = mc.getTileheight();
    int dx1 = 0;
    int dx2 = dx1+tilewidth;
    int dy1 = 0;
    int dy2 = dy1+tileheight;
    int sx1 = x*tilewidth;
    int sx2 = sx1+tilewidth;
    int sy1 = y*tileheight;
    int sy2 = sy1+tileheight;
    g.drawImage(mc.getSpriteImage(), dx1, dy1, dx2, dy2, sx1, sy1, sx2, sy2,      null);

}
```